# How to save WAV file with script in praat?

Tags: praat

I try to save a praat sound object to wav file. There is no problem when I do it in GUI. But it complains "Sounds not concatenated and not saved" in script. Does anyone know why?

Here is the command line output:

```
~/Downloads$ /Applications/Praat.app/Contents/MacOS/Praat --run aa1.praat 
Error: Cannot create file “/Users/hgneng/Downloads/"/Users/hgneng/Downloads/aa2.wav"”.
Sounds not concatenated and not saved to “/Users/hgneng/Downloads/"/Users/hgneng/Downloads/aa2.wav"”.
Script line 15 not performed or completed:
« Save as WAV file... "/Users/hgneng/Downloads/aa2.wav" »
Script “/Users/hgneng/Downloads/aa1.praat” not completed.
Praat: script command <<aa1.praat>> not completed.
```

Here is the content of praat script:

```
sound = Read from file: "/Users/hgneng/e-guidedog/jyutping-wong/aa1.wav"
endtime = Get end time
To Manipulation... 0.01 75 600
selectObject: sound
Create DurationTier: "aa1", 0, endtime
Add point: 0, 3
selectObject: "Manipulation aa1"
plusObject: "DurationTier aa1"
Replace duration tier
minusObject: "DurationTier aa1"
Get resynthesis (overlap-add)
removeObject: sound
removeObject: "Manipulation aa1"
removeObject: "DurationTier aa1"
Save as WAV file... "/Users/hgneng/Downloads/aa2.wav"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
Save as WAV file... "/Users/hgneng/Downloads/aa2.wav"
```

to

```
Save as WAV file: "/Users/hgneng/Downloads/aa2.wav"
```

will fix the issue.

Comment: The so-called _shorthand_ syntax also works, but in that case you don't need the quotes. So `Save as WAV file... /Users/hgneng/Downloads/aa2.wav` would also have worked. The reason it wasn't working is because the last argument to a _shorthand_ command or procedure is an unquoted string. So in your original line, the quotes were part of the filename.